# how to create an angular templateref in code

Tags: angular, typescript, templates

I need to create an instance of `TemplateRef` in the .ts file and pass this as a parameter to a component.  Is it possible to do this.  What I want to do is to just create an instance of a TemplateRef with some content inside.  I tried searching the web but couldn't find any concrete example on this.

Comment: Unfortunately the angular team has announced that it will not support it. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15275